# external css not getting applied to div

Tags: css

It is working when i apply it as inline style.

```
<div id="footer">@Copyright 2012</div>

 #footer
 {
    background-color:Black;
    color:Silver;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
 }
```

Comment: Is the external CSS included after the other CSS? The latest CSS file will overwrite the previous.

Answer (score 1):

Look with `Firebug` which style is *winning* over your.

Please note that the **order of declaration** of your `CSS`s in your page matters, last win.

So you probably have another `#footer` rule in another stylesheet loaded after your.